# Delete an object from an array of objects inside an Object

Tags: javascript, object

I am not sure how to form this question, but I will do my best.
I want to remove an object from an array `produits` that is inside the parent object, depending on the `families.name` that must equal a string from the initial object that I want to delete ( I already achieved this part).

Right now I'm stuck and don't know how to update the initial `Parent` object, I was able to delete the object from the array produits.

The parent Object:

```
let Parent = {
    "Id": "60f03c42a512e04c4b0161e7",
    "familles": [{
            "name": "LOV D+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                    "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
                    "type": "fabricant",
                    "parent_uid": null,
                    "version_application": "1.1.0",
                    "creation_date": null,
                    "titu": "REST1",
                    "ref_cstb": "162367462",
                    "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
                    "serie": "PREMIERE",
                    "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
                    "usines": null
                },
                {
                    "uid": "QB32N-20210720-75584",
                    "type": "fabricant",
                    "parent_uid": null,
                    "version_application": "1.1.0",
                    "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:34:04.49Z",
                    "titu": "REST1",
                    "ref_cstb": "ref-18-taieb",
                    "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                    "serie": "WIND",
                    "description": null,
                    "usines": null
                }
            ],
            "version_schema": null
        },
        {
            "name": "LOV F+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                "uid": "ITEM-20210720-33547",
                "type": "fabricant",
                "parent_uid": null,
                "version_application": "1.1.0",
                "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:46:37.649Z",
                "titu": "REST1",
                "ref_cstb": "ref19-taieb",
                "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                "serie": "STOCKHOLM",
                "description": null,
                "usines": null
            }],
            "version_schema": null
        }
    ]
}
```

The object I want to delete

```
let obj1 = {
    "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
    "type": "fabricant",
    "parent_uid": null,
    "version_application": "1.1.0",
    "creation_date": null,
    "titu": "REST1",
    "ref_cstb": "162367462",
    "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
    "serie": "PREMIERE",
    "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
    "usines": null,
    "group": "QB - LOV D+",
    "parent": "QB"
}
```

So that my Parent Object will look like this

```
let Parent = {
    "Id": "60f03c42a512e04c4b0161e7",
    "familles": [{
            "name": "LOV D+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                "uid": "ITEM-20210720-75584",
                "type": "fabricant",
                "parent_uid": null,
                "version_application": "1.1.0",
                "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:34:04.49Z",
                "titu": "REST1",
                "ref_cstb": "ref-18-taieb",
                "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                "serie": "WIND",
                "description": null,
                "usines": null
            }],
            "version_schema": null
        },
        {
            "name": "LOV F+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                "uid": "ITEM-20210720-33547",
                "type": "fabricant",
                "parent_uid": null,
                "version_application": "1.1.0",
                "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:46:37.649Z",
                "titu": "REST1",
                "ref_cstb": "ref19-taieb",
                "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                "serie": "STOCKHOLM",
                "description": null,
                "usines": null
            }],
            "version_schema": null
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have so far done:

```
    Remove(obj, parentObj) {

        let a = e.group.split("-").pop().slice(1)
        console.log(a) // Will Display LOV D+ 
        let newArray = this.certificat.familles.find((x: {
            name: any;
        }) => x.name === a); // Will display the proper object that have the name = LOV D+
        newArray = newArray.produits.filter(({
            uid
        }) => {
            return uid !== e.uid;
        }); // This will delete the object from the array, but it will not update the parent object, I'm missing something here 
    }

Remove(obj1, parent)
```

Comment: Why `.filter()`? Do you need a copy of the array? Is an in-place delete with `.splice()` (and `.findIndex()`) an option?

Comment: Yes that's what missing, how I can reassigning it to the parent? or modify directly the parent ?

Comment: `newArray.produits = newArray.produits.filter(...)`

Comment: Is there way to do it without the newArray ? I mean without creating a new object and modify directly the parent? I don't know if it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: See my first comment. Find the index (`.findIndex()`) of the element you want to remove and then use `.splice()` to remove that element.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let Parent = {
    "Id": "60f03c42a512e04c4b0161e7",
    "familles": [{
            "name": "LOV D+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                    "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
                    "type": "fabricant",
                    "parent_uid": null,
                    "version_application": "1.1.0",
                    "creation_date": null,
                    "titu": "REST1",
                    "ref_cstb": "162367462",
                    "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
                    "serie": "PREMIERE",
                    "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
                    "usines": null
                },
                {
                    "uid": "QB32N-20210720-75584",
                    "type": "fabricant",
                    "parent_uid": null,
                    "version_application": "1.1.0",
                    "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:34:04.49Z",
                    "titu": "REST1",
                    "ref_cstb": "ref-18-taieb",
                    "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                    "serie": "WIND",
                    "description": null,
                    "usines": null
                }
            ],
            "version_schema": null
        },
        {
            "name": "LOV F+",
            "parent": "QB",
            "produits": [{
                "uid": "ITEM-20210720-33547",
                "type": "fabricant",
                "parent_uid": null,
                "version_application": "1.1.0",
                "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:46:37.649Z",
                "titu": "REST1",
                "ref_cstb": "ref19-taieb",
                "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
                "serie": "STOCKHOLM",
                "description": null,
                "usines": null
            }],
            "version_schema": null
        }
    ]
}


let obj1 = {
    "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
    "type": "fabricant",
    "parent_uid": null,
    "version_application": "1.1.0",
    "creation_date": null,
    "titu": "REST1",
    "ref_cstb": "162367462",
    "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
    "serie": "PREMIERE",
    "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
    "usines": null,
    "group": "QB - LOV D+",
    "parent": "QB"
}

function filterParent(obj, parentObj) {
  
    let a = obj.group.split("-").pop().slice(1) 
    let newArray = parentObj.familles.map((x) => x.name !== a ? x : {...x, produits:x.produits.filter(matchUID)}); 
  
  function matchUID(produit){
    return produit.uid !== obj.uid
  }
  return {...parentObj, familles:newArray}
}

Parent = filterParent(obj1, Parent)

console.log(Parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This will splice the object with matching `name` and `uid` from `Parent`, like you want.

```js
let Parent = {
  "Id": "60f03c42a512e04c4b0161e7",
  "familles": [{
      "name": "LOV D+",
      "parent": "QB",
      "produits": [{
          "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
          "type": "fabricant",
          "parent_uid": null,
          "version_application": "1.1.0",
          "creation_date": null,
          "titu": "REST1",
          "ref_cstb": "162367462",
          "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
          "serie": "PREMIERE",
          "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
          "usines": null
        },
        {
          "uid": "QB32N-20210720-75584",
          "type": "fabricant",
          "parent_uid": null,
          "version_application": "1.1.0",
          "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:34:04.49Z",
          "titu": "REST1",
          "ref_cstb": "ref-18-taieb",
          "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
          "serie": "WIND",
          "description": null,
          "usines": null
        }
      ],
      "version_schema": null
    },
    {
      "name": "LOV F+",
      "parent": "QB",
      "produits": [{
        "uid": "ITEM-20210720-33547",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "parent_uid": null,
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-20T14:46:37.649Z",
        "titu": "REST1",
        "ref_cstb": "ref19-taieb",
        "gamme": "SUPERGRES T_20",
        "serie": "STOCKHOLM",
        "description": null,
        "usines": null
      }],
      "version_schema": null
    }
  ]
}

let obj1 = {
  "uid": "ITEM-20210715-20758",
  "type": "fabricant",
  "parent_uid": null,
  "version_application": "1.1.0",
  "creation_date": null,
  "titu": "REST1",
  "ref_cstb": "162367462",
  "gamme": "SUPERGRES",
  "serie": "PREMIERE",
  "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
  "usines": null,
  "group": "QB - LOV D+",
  "parent": "QB"
}

function Remove(obj, parentObj) {
  let famille = parentObj.familles.findIndex((x) => x.name === obj.group.split(" - ").pop());
  let produit = parentObj.familles[famille].produits.findIndex((x) => x.uid === obj.uid);
  parentObj.familles[famille].produits.splice(produit, 1);
}

Remove(obj1, Parent);

console.log(Parent);
```

Comment: When there is only one Element in the array, it will not delete it, I think because we are displaying the last state before the splice ?

Comment: What do you mean? If there is only one object in the `produits` array, then the array is emptied. Do you also require the `famille` to be removed at that point too?

Answer (score -1):

You can search for the index of the particular element/object and then delete it using

> delete Parent.familles[0].produits[0]

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
      console.log(fruits.indexOf("Apple"))
```